# Find variable name and store it for later reference

Tags: java, variables

I want to be able to find the variable name of an object that has already been checked for if it has been called. And then store this variable name inside either an array or other form of storage for later reference. Here is the code in it's unfinished state.

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class errorHelpImproved
    {
     //Needs Scanner to detect what's in the line
       public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     //Create a section that reads line by line and finds commands that aren't imported
        public static void import1(File file)
        {
           /*logic note: 
              read line by line
              IF a line contains the keyword Scanner
                   -Set a flag to check for the keyphrase import java.util.Scanner; OR import java.util.*;
                   -If neither keyphrase found before the first instance of a keyword public class
                       +Then Scanner has been called without the package being imported
                   -If either keyphrase found, stop searching and add this Scanner variable to an array of Scanner variables
           */
          File fileStart = new File(file);
          do
          {
             String line = file.nextLine();
             if(line.contains(" Scanner "))
             {
                 boolean flagTest=false;
                 String line2;
                 do
                 {
                    line2 = fileStart.nextLine;
                    if(line2.contains("import java.util.*;") || line2.contains("import java.util.Scanner;"))
                    {   
                       flagTest=true;
                       break;
                    }
                 }while(!line2.contains("public class"))
                 if(flagTest == false)
                 {
                      System.out.println("Scanner class has been called without being imported.");
                 }
                 else if(flagTest == true)
                 {
                   //This is where it would find the word after scanner and store it
                 }
              }
          }while(file.hasNext());
    }
        //Main method gets name of file and passes it to the first check and then from there all other codes will use it
        public static void main(Strings [] args)
        {
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```

Cause I've thought about this for almost a week and I have no idea how I would go about this.

Comment: Don't store the variable name. Instead, try making an ArrayList, and putting the object itself in there.

Comment: you really should be using a true parser, using antlr, for instance.

Comment: @MikiP Except I want to store the variable name as I plan on the next step after this scans and finds all possible variable types I need it to find, that it then will scan through and find every possible indication of a line that contains a keyphrase for that object type, and see if the variable it references is in the list of all possible variables and if not, say that it isn't in the list.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy Except this is a honor's project for college and it's meant to be done without the use of outside frameworks.

Comment: Heh, as a student i get your point. But you would learn so much more using antlr, than some cheesy hand build parser. Your professor should be ashamed of him/herself

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy Okay but for an entry level class about learning to program in Java, I don't think it's necessarily a viable alternative to do something she isn't meant to be teaching us.

Comment: parsing a java file format by hand is ridiculous, even more so for entry level.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy Well it's the assignment I have to do in order to get Higher level credit. It's not a project everyone is working on, it's one I had to set up with her beforehand and discuss what it would be. Since it has to be a project that gives higher level credit towards a distinguishment at the university, she told me to create a program in java that can read .java files and output all potential problems with the program.

Comment: Well, that's pretty advanced: *output all potential problems with the program* :-) I suggest you write a program that executes first the Java Compiler on the java classes and then run jlint (http://jlint.sourceforge.net/) on the code. That should be pretty much state of the art and I think you can actually really code that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Scanning .java files for declarations and reading the variable name is more complex than this. You can do it like this, but java code has no requirement for linebreaks. A java application is fine to be written in one line.

The same is true for adding linebreaks. You can add a linebreak wherever a whitespace is allowed in the code.

```
Scanner sVar;
Scanner
    sVar2;
```

Are both legal java code. Your approach will also match text literals and comments:

```
/* This is a line with the Scanner variable */ 
String value = "I am fooling the Scanner code with this line and the comment above";
```

Reading your comments above: The java compiler does what your teacher asked you for. You can run the java compiler using the `javax.tools` package. See more information here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html#getSystemJavaCompiler()

Having said that, you must accept restrictions to your approach: The code must be "well formatted" to match your search criteria, otherwise you will have false positives or bad matches.

- consider that each line containing " Scanner " is in fact a variable definition or declaration.
- The word after Scanner is not a comment and we suppose it to be the variable name.
- There is only one Scanner defined per line. (No `Scanner sA, sB;` or `Scanner sA; Scanner sB;`)
- Furthermore, you store the list of matches in a List for later processing (write to file).

Then the missing code could look like this:

```
else if(flagTest == true)
{
    //This is where it would find the word after scanner and store it
    int pos = line.indexOf("Scanner") + "Scanner ".length();
    String varStart = line.substring(pos);
    pos = varStart.indexOf(";");
    String varName = varStart.substring(0, pos).trim();
    variableNames.add(varName);
}
```

This will be less restrictive, if you run it with a regular expression matcher on the line, that has a match-group for the variable name. But I think this is maybe more confusing for your coding level.

A regular expression with a matching group should look like this: `.*Scanner\s+([a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z_0-9$]*)[\s;].*`